# How to run many threads/procs with global timeout

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run many python threads (or separate processes) from the 'run' method of class GetDayMin.  I want the threads or processes to run simultaneously, and after 40 seconds the class instance writes it's data (from each thread/proc) and exits.  While I can start each thread without waiting on anything to complete, if I use the join method to wait on any thread, it could take a long time to timeout since successive threads may all be blocked.  It seems the join method of both threading and multiprocessing will hang until the timeout.

For example, if in my class I start 5 threads and then wait 40 seconds in order of thread creation, the first thread could take 40 seconds to timeout, and then we go to the second thread with takes 40 seconds to timeout etc.  We could end up waiting 200 seconds for 5 threads.

What I want is that no thread takes longer than 40 seconds, so the whole class instance lasts a maximum of 40 seconds too.  I'm willing to do multiprocessing instead of multithreading if that makes things easier.  What I really anticipate is that most threads will complete within 10 seconds but three or four may hang, and I don't want to wait for them. How can I accomplish this?

```
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd
import random
import time

class GetDayMin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.results = pd.DataFrame()  # Shared DataFrame to store results

    def add_result(self, result):
        self.results = self.results.append(result, ignore_index=True)

    def process_function(self):
        sleep_time = random.randint(30, 50)  # Random sleep time between 30 to 50 seconds
        time.sleep(sleep_time)  # Pretend I'm calculating something
        
        # Return the time slept to store in the results to simulate thread communication
        return {'process_id': multiprocessing.current_process().pid, 'time_slept': sleep_time}

    def run(self):
        processes = []
        for _ in range(30):
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.process_function)
            processes.append(process)

        # Start all processes
        for process in processes:
            process.start()

        # Wait for all processes to finish or timeout after 40 seconds (each--unfortunately)
        for process in processes:
            process.join(timeout=40)
            if process.is_alive():
                process.terminate()
                process.join()  # wait on process--want this to be a collective 40 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you can compute an absolute time `expiration_time` when all submitted tasks should have completed and if any are still running after that time they should be terminated. The amount of time you specify on `process.join()` can be computed from that `expiration_time` and the current time:

```py
...
    def run(self):
        processes = []
        for _ in range(30):
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.process_function)
            processes.append(process)

        # Start all processes
        for process in processes:
            process.start()

        # Wait for all processes to finish or timeout after 40 seconds
        expiration_time = time.time() + 40
        time_expired = False
        for process in processes:
            if time_expired:
                process.terminate()
            else:
                wait_time = expiration_time - time.time()
                if wait_time <= 0:
                    process.terminate()
                    time_expired = True
                else:
                    process.join(timeout=wait_time)
                    if process.is_alive():
                        process.terminate()
                        time_expired = True
```

**But Consider This**

You can see my answer above, which only addresses your timing issue, but I also wanted to mention that if your actual `process_function` calls method `add_result` the results will not be what you expected because each process will see its own copy of the `dataframe`. Also, you have method `process_function` returning a value. But you cannot return a value back to the caller form a process instance that way. You might want the following:

```py
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd
import random
import time

class GetDayMin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.results = pd.DataFrame()  # Shared DataFrame to store results

    def add_result(self, result):
        self.results = self.results.append(result, ignore_index=True)

    def process_function(self, results_dict):
        sleep_time = random.randint(30, 50)  # Random sleep time between 30 to 50 seconds
        time.sleep(sleep_time)  # Pretend I'm calculating something

        # Return the time slept to store in the results to simulate thread communication
        results_dict[multiprocessing.current_process().pid] = sleep_time

    def run(self):
        with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
            results_dict = manager.dict()
            processes = [
                multiprocessing.Process(target=self.process_function, args=(results_dict,))
                for _ in range(30)
            ]

            # Start all processes
            for process in processes:
                process.start()

            # Wait for all processes to finish or timeout after 40 seconds
            start_time = time.time()
            expiration_time = start_time + 40
            time_expired = False
            for process in processes:
                if time_expired:
                    process.terminate()
                else:
                    wait_time = expiration_time - time.time()
                    if wait_time <= 0:
                        process.terminate()
                        time_expired = True
                    else:
                        process.join(timeout=wait_time)
                        if process.is_alive():
                            process.terminate()
                            time_expired = True

            end_time = time.time()
            print(f'Total elapsed time: {end_time - start_time} seconds')
            for pid, sleep_time in results_dict.items():
                print(f'Process {pid} slept for {sleep_time} seconds')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GetDayMin().run()
```

Prints:

```None
Total elapsed time: 40.00496006011963 seconds
Process 500 slept for 30 seconds
Process 504 slept for 30 seconds
Process 466 slept for 32 seconds
Process 512 slept for 33 seconds
Process 461 slept for 34 seconds
Process 470 slept for 35 seconds
Process 455 slept for 36 seconds
Process 459 slept for 36 seconds
Process 491 slept for 36 seconds
Process 472 slept for 37 seconds
Process 507 slept for 37 seconds
Process 486 slept for 39 seconds
Process 463 slept for 40 seconds
Process 477 slept for 40 seconds
```

The same can be accomplished with a multiprocessing pool. In this case given your worker function `process_function` if we have a pool of size N and we submit N tasks to the pool, each pool process will process a single task. The advantage of using a pool is that the worker function is able to directly return a result and we therefore don't need to use a managed dictionary.

```py
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd
import random
import time

class GetDayMin:
    def process_function(self):
        sleep_time = random.randint(30, 50)  # Random sleep time between 30 to 50 seconds
        time.sleep(sleep_time)  # Pretend I'm calculating something

        # Return the time slept to store in the results to simulate thread communication
        return multiprocessing.current_process().pid, sleep_time

    def run(self):
        results = {}

        n_tasks = 30
        with multiprocessing.Pool(n_tasks) as pool:
            async_results = [
                pool.apply_async(self.process_function)
                for _ in range(n_tasks)
            ]

            # Wait for all processes to finish or timeout after 40 seconds
            start_time = time.time()
            expiration_time = start_time + 40
            for async_result in async_results:
                wait_time = expiration_time - time.time()
                if wait_time <= 0:
                    # Time has expired and we cannot wait for the task to complete.
                    # So has the task already completed:
                    if async_result.ready():
                        # The task has completed and so
                        # this should not block:
                        pid, sleep_time = async_result.get()
                        results[pid] = sleep_time
                else:
                    # The time has not expired so we are willing to wait
                    # a certain amount of time for the result:
                    try:
                        pid, sleep_time = async_result.get(wait_time)
                    except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
                        # We will not get a result from this task
                        pass
                    else:
                        results[pid] = sleep_time
        # When we exit the above block all remaining tasks will be cancelled

        end_time = time.time()
        print(f'Total elapsed time: {end_time - start_time} seconds')
        for pid, sleep_time in results.items():
            print(f'Process {pid} slept for {sleep_time} seconds')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GetDayMin().run()
```

Prints:

```None
Total elapsed time: 40.01216197013855 seconds
Process 832 slept for 32 seconds
Process 833 slept for 35 seconds
Process 834 slept for 35 seconds
Process 837 slept for 31 seconds
Process 844 slept for 38 seconds
Process 846 slept for 34 seconds
Process 849 slept for 31 seconds
Process 851 slept for 36 seconds
Process 852 slept for 35 seconds
Process 853 slept for 30 seconds
Process 854 slept for 39 seconds
Process 856 slept for 31 seconds
Process 857 slept for 37 seconds
Process 859 slept for 38 seconds
Process 860 slept for 36 seconds
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, thank you!  I don't understand why each process has its own dataframe when the dataframe exists in the main process.  Couldn't I add a callback to the pool workers that call a class function to modify a class variable (when locking it) and have it be what I expect, the totality of the returned data?

Comment: Every process runs with its own address space. You create an instance of `GetDayMin` in the main process and it has a `results` attribute that is a `dataframe`. All of this resides in the memory of the main process. You then create one or more processes where the worker function is a method of the `GetDayMin` instance. On Linux when child processes are created using *fork* these child processes inherit the main process's memory with *copy on write* so effectively the child process cannot modify any memory belonging to the main process. (more...)

Comment: To be able to do so, the "object" being modified must be stored in "shared memory" (see `multiprocessing.Array` or the `multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory` class as examples). Storing a dataframe in SharedMemory is not straightforward. If you are using a multiprocessing pool you can readily values back to the main process or if using `multiprocessing.Process` instances, they can write data to a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance that the main process can read from. You don't show in your code where `add_result` is being called, so I can't tell you more than this. But ... (more...)

Comment: ... just like in my last code example`process_function` is returning a tuple '(pid, sleep_time)` it can return anything that can be serialized with `pickle` and the main process can retrieve this data with `async_result.get()` and then use that data to update its local copy of the dataframe just like I am currently updating dictionary `results`. But if all your submitted tasks running in the pool processes need to see updated versions of the dataframe, you are out of luck.